# Qtableview is not updating when table model updates

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I am writing a gui application for processing multiple Excel files into a single file. The main window displays a table to which the user can add or remove files to be collected in the larger file. Each row will represent a file with columns for different parameters (data to be pulled from that file.) I've been working on implementing a QAbstractTableModel for this purpose, which works great, although I've not been able to update the table view. When a new row is added to my array of data, a new row is added to the table view but each column is empty. I'm not sure why this is as I've confirmed that the data array is updating as it should. Example:

```
class _tableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)

        self.data = data
        self.load_data(data)

    def load_data(self, data):
        self.input_files = data[:,0]
        self.input_sheets = data[:,1]

        self.column_count = 2
        self.row_count = len(self.input_sheets)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.row_count

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.column_count

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return ("File", "Sheet")[section]
        else:
            return "{}".format(section)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0:
                file = str(self.input_files[row])
                return file
            elif column == 1:
                return str(self.input_sheets[row])
        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QColor(Qt.white)
        elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignRight

        return None

    def appendRowData(self, data):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.data = np.concatenate((self.data, data), axis=0)
        self.endInsertRows()


    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.addFileButton = QPushButton('Add File')
        self.addFileButton.clicked.connect(self.addFileDialog)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.addFileButton)

        self.model = _tableModel(data)

        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.model)

        self.horizontal_header = self.table_view.horizontalHeader()
        self.vertical_header = self.table_view.verticalHeader()
        self.horizontal_header.setSectionResizeMode(
                               QHeaderView.ResizeToContents
                               )
        self.vertical_header.setSectionResizeMode(
                             QHeaderView.ResizeToContents
                             )
        self.horizontal_header.setStretchLastSection(True)

        size = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        size.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        self.table_view.setSizePolicy(size)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.table_view)

        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

    def addFileDialog(self):
        self.fileWizard = QDialog()

        self.wiz_layout = QFormLayout()
        self.fileWizard.setLayout(self.wiz_layout)

        self.selectExcelFile = QPushButton('Select Excel File')
        self.selectExcelFile.clicked.connect(self.selectexcel)
        self.wiz_layout.addRow(self.selectExcelFile)

        self.selectedFileDisplay = QTextEdit()
        self.wiz_layout.addRow(self.selectedFileDisplay)

        self.sheet = QLineEdit()
        self.wiz_layout.addRow('Sheet Name: ', self.sheet)

        self.add_to_table = QPushButton('Add to File Table')
        self.wiz_layout.addWidget(self.add_to_table)
        self.add_to_table.clicked.connect(self._addTableEntry)

        self.fileWizard.show()

    def selectexcel(self):
        self.filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
        self.filename = self.filename[0]

        self.selectedFileDisplay.setText(self.filename)
        pass

    def _addTableEntry(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        data = np.array([[self.filename, self.sheet.text()]])
        self.model.appendRowData(data)


class _mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.generalLayout = QGridLayout()

        data = np.array([['File name here','Sheet name here']])
        self._centralWidget = Widget(data)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = _mainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `rowCount` and `columnCount` must be dynamic, since they return the *current* extent of the model.

You're setting those values as static, so, while the model "accepts" the insertion of rows (as shown in the view), it's not able to access them because the row and column count don't reflect the updated model size.

```
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.data[:,1])
```

Note that you're also *not* updating the `self.data` but in fact replacing it. Since you're using `self.input_files` for `data()`, it will probably result in an exception, as those arrays are not actually updated.

So, you either *always* use `self.data` anywhere with the correct slices, or use python properties to access `input_files` and `input_sheets`.

```
class _tableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...
    @property
    def input_files(self):
        return self.data[:,0]
    # ...
```

Comment: You were right on every count here, implementing `rowCount` and `columnCount` in the way you suggested worked, and I've updated `input_files` and `input_sheets` to use properties. I'm not sure if properties are the best way forward for this particular case, however, since I need to add a lot more parameters to the input files and - if I'm understanding correctly - would have to define and call new properties for each new parameter. Slicing may be the way to go here. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @George You're welcome! Consider that using properties was a suggestion that, in this case, is just for convenience since it does the same thing. You can implement both `data` and `setData` in any way you want, the point is that since your data could be updated, and since this requires replacing the existing array, you should always use the dynamic reference to it. An important note: naming the array `self.data` is not a good idea, as technically `data` is the function used to access the model. It works due to the way Qt accesses functions, but you should use another name for the source array.